# Unable to dismiss UIViewController when it is presenting UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am trying dismiss a `UIViewController` that is currently presenting a `UIAlertController` as follows,

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController {

    private var alertController: UIAlertController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        presentAlert()
    }

    fucn presentAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "alert", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .destructive, handler: {
            dismiss(animated: true)
        }))
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
            self.alertController = alertController
        })
    }

    override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

        // alertController?.dismiss(animated: true)
        /*This dismisses SampleViewController when user taps Cancel
         but I want user to stay on this screen when they tap Cancel*/

        super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}

class currentViewController: UIViewController {
    private let sampleViewController = SampleViewController()

    func presentSampleViewController() {
        present(sampleViewController, animated: true)
    }

    func dismissSampleViewController() {
        sampleViewController.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

But only the alert gets dismissed not the entire `SampleViewController` also I couldn't find if `override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)` is called from `CurrentViewController` or `UIAlertController` action.

I would like to dismiss both `alert` and `SampleViewController` together and take the user back to `CurrentViewController`. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)` in `dismissSampleViewController()` instead of `sampleViewController.dismiss(animated: true)`

By dismissing `CurrentViewController` you'll dismiss all of it's children view controllers

Comment: Call `dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)` in `dismissSampleViewController` instead of `sampleViewController.dismiss(animated: true)`

Comment: Please note I have mentioned that I would like to dismiss both ```alert``` and ```SampleViewController``` together and take the user back to ```CurrentViewController```.

Comment: Correct, I think what I mentioned should work? By dismissing `CurrentViewController` you'll dismiss all of it's children view controllers.

Comment: Yes this worked, thanks for the clarification. Please update your answer so that I can accept it.